# Getting "Error 321:ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING" when trying to open PDF in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, rest, jakarta-ee

I has written the REST web service to download the PDF file from the server and sends the response as content-type=application/pdf to the browser.Below is the REST service url ,which we are calling to download PDF file from the server is throwing "Error 321:ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING" when opening the PDF file in the browser

```
Window.open("https://www.somedomain.com/appservice/resource/pdf")
```

The same web service, if we are calling with out using SSL(using http) and using ip ,port  ,is working good.Below is the REST service Url,which displays the PDF file correctely.

```
Window.open("http://ip:port/appservice/resource/pdf")
```

For downloading the images from server ,Both the services (Http and Https) are working good,Only with the PDF files , I am getting this issue...

Is this issue is because of SSL configuration ? If so how it is working for Image?
Please let me know ,how to fix this..

Answer (score 3):

My problem got solved by adding  the Content-Length to the response header , the length of the file in bytes.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Length", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be a cache-control issue.  If you can control the headers that are sent back to the client (which I'm guessing you can if you're building & streaming back a PDF), try adding these to the https response and see what happens:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "");
```

Comment: I added the following code, it is not working .same error is coming.